How to apply dependent rules in a complex expression?
I am working with a complex expression, $L_0$, which I need to simplify iteratively using a series of dependent replacement rules. Here's the structured approach I am trying to implement:

Start with the initial expression $L_0$.

Apply a set of rules $r_1$ that depend on another list of expressions $E_1$, replacing elements of $E_1$ with values $v_1$:
$$
L_1 = L_0 /. r_1(E_1 \rightarrow v_1)
$$
where $r_1(E_1 \rightarrow v_1)$ defines as $r_1=\{E_{1,i} \rightarrow v_{1,i}\}$ for $i=1,...,\text{Length}[E_1]$.

For the next replacing, I need first to replace elements in $E_2$ using the previously applied rules $r_1$, and then construct a new set of rules $r_2$ to apply to $L_1$:
$$
L_2 = L_1 /. r_2(E_2 /. r_1(E_1 \rightarrow v_1), v_2)
$$

This process continues iteratively, where $E_n$ is transformed by all previous rules before constructing and applying the next set of rules:
$$
L_3 = L_2 /. r_3(E_3 /. r_1(E_1 \rightarrow v_1) /. r_2(E_2 \rightarrow v_2), v_3)
$$
so $E_3$ needs to be replaced by both $r_1$ and $r_2$.

And so on, up to:


$$
L_n = L_{n-1} /. r_n(E_n /. r_1 /. r_2 /. \cdots /. r_{n-1}, v_n)
$$
The goal is to achieve a simplified expression $L_n$ after $n$ steps. I attempted using Nest, but it only worked correctly for the first couple of iterations. The challenge lies in dynamically maintaining and applying the sequence of transformations $r_1, ..., r_{n-1}$ within Nest or any similar construct without success, as ReplaceAll needs to be applied multiple times in sequence to $E_n$.
My attempt at this is:
Nest[{#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]] /. #[[3]], 
    MapIndexed[
     Function[{e, i}, Rule[e[[1]], Subscript[v[#[[1]] + 1], i[[1]]]]],
      exp[#[[1]] + 1] /. #[[3]]]} &, {1, L0, 
   MapIndexed[Rule[#1[[1]], Subscript[h[1], #2[[1]]]] &, exp[1]]}, 
  n][[2]]Nest[{#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]] /. #[[3]], 
    MapIndexed[
     Function[{e, i}, Rule[e[[1]], Subscript[v[#[[1]] + 1], i[[1]]]]],
      exp[#[[1]] + 1] /. #[[3]]]} &, {1, L0, 
   MapIndexed[Rule[#1[[1]], Subscript[v[1], #2[[1]]]] &, exp[1]]}, 
  n][[2]] (*exp[i] outputs E_i as a column vector*)

It only works when n=1,2.
Since the expressions involved are complex, I am unable to provide a minimal working example. However, I hope the explanation above is clear enough. How can I implement this expression replacing in Mathematica effectively, better with a functional style?

What about ReplaceRepeated?

This fixes the problem, thanks @JieZhu!
Nest[{#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]] //. #[[3]],
Flatten@AppendTo[#[[3]],
MapIndexed[
Function[{e, i},
Rule[e[[1]], Subscript[v[#[[1]] + 1], i[[1]]]]],
exp[#[[1]] + 1] //. #[[3]]]]} &, {1, L0,
MapIndexed[Rule[#1[[1]], Subscript[h[1], #2[[1]]]] &, exp[1]]},
n][[2]]
